# How to reformat list data?

Tags: python, list

I use pyodbc in python and I return data and the data look like this

```
[28, 27, 26,...,5]
```

I want the data look like this

```
[28],[27],[26],...,[5]
```

How I get the data:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT top 100 ....")
result = cursor.fetchall()
sumresult = []
for row in result:
    sumresult.append(row[0])
    return sumresult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use **list comprehension**:

```
input = [28, 27, 26, 5]           
output = [[i] for i in input]
```

Executing this code results in `output` being: `[[28], [27], [26], [5]]`

Hope this helps

Comment: This is really helps me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just trying to get a list of single-element lists, you could do something like this:

```
>>> L = range(10)

>>> print(L)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

>>> print([ [i] for i in L ])
[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

Comment: This is really helps me. Thank you.